# Make a class thread safe/suitable for concurrent access

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a class written in C# and I want to make sure it's thread safe. Basically what properties need to be in the critical section (locked), in the constructor and methods.

I was thinking about locking just the age because it's an int. Also because FirstName and LastName it's readonly - it should be threadsafe.

```
public class User
{
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    private readonly string FirstName;
    private readonly string LastName;

    private string Address;
    private int Age;

    public User(string firstName, string lastName, string address, int age){
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Age = age;
        Address = address;
    }
    public string GetName()
    {

        return FirstName +LastName;

    }
      public void UpdateAge(int age)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {

            Age = Age;
        }
    }
    public int GetAge()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return Age;
        }
    }
    public string GetAddress()
    {

        return Address;

    }
```

}

Comment: side step the problem: store birthdate and make class immutable.

Comment: It's not clear what you think thread safety means here. `age` is an `int` - updating its value is atomic anyway.

Comment: Basically, different threads will use the object based on this class to get/modify the fields and I want to make sure these operations are consistent/thread-safe.

Comment: Can you describe an example of an inconsistent operation? For example "thread-A does this to an object, thread-B does that to the same object, and then the thread-C observes that the state of the object is XYZ, which is an invalid state for the object."

Comment: Thread A calls UpdateAge method while ThreadB call GetAge 
Thread A, B calls "GetAddress" in the same time.
Thread A,B,C create new objects concurrently (constructor is called).

These are the kinds of operations.

Comment: I am asking about a series of operations that would bring an object to an invalid state, assuming that there is such thing as an invalid state for these objects. Because if all states are valid and self-consistent, then I can't see what could go wrong.